# Do Geth and Parity nodes have the same txpool?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, txpool

If I broadcast a transaction using a parity node, will it be more likely to be included in a block if the miner is also using Parity?  or do geth miners have an equal chance to include the transaction?

Answer (score 3):

you have an equal chance to get your transaction mined, transaction brodcasting doesn't depend on wich client you are using. However parity is known to be faster, because geth doesn't have an optimization that Partiy has

Comment: does this optimization have any impact on how quickly your transaction gets inlcuded in a block? I assume no

Comment: no as you said, besides geth is most client used by miners.